# php magic method to catch array_push

Tags: php, arrays, magic-methods, array-push

I am looking for a way to intercept the action in [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push), because when it will be retrieve it each value of the array has another info like:

```
class ClassName {

    var $test = array();

    function __set($attr, $value) {
      $this->$attr = 'My extra value'.$value;
    }    

    function index(){
      array_push($this->test, "some val");
      array_push($this->test, "some other val");

      print_r($this->test);

    }
}

$o = new ClassName();
$o->index();
```

And expected to get something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => My extra value some val
    [1] => My extra value some other val
)
```

But i get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some val
    [1] => some other val
)
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Hmm, I have problems to understand what your issue is. Are you concerned that your code actually works? Because this does not look wrong and you don't need to intercept anything.

Comment: @hakre: He's trying to add a prefix to all elements added to the `$test` property of `ClassName`.  The code he has does not work.

Comment: `test` is public therefore accessible so `__set()` won't be called. I'm not 100% certain but internally PHP might call get on your `test` property first.. append the value with `array_push()` then call set with the new value. Not sure if that helps.. just a hidden behavior of php.

Comment: This code doesnt throw the array as i expected, i will acomplish the explination

Comment: I think @mike is on the money: change `var $test` to `private $test`

Comment: sorry Mike B, i dont understand your suggest :S, i have made `test` private ( `private $test` ), but still, php doesnt get in to the __set function

Comment: private properties are still accessible within the same class. You won't be able to trigger `__set()` like that. The only way to trigger it within the same class is to call it explicitly `$this->__set('test', 'my values');` or remove/rename the property declaration making it inaccessible. A lot of times these kinds of variables will be created as protected properties prefixed with an underscore so `__set()` will be triggered. i.e. have a property `protected $_test` then when you go to `$this->test = 'my values'` have `__set()` catch that and add an underscore to the name and set the value.

Comment: `__set()` only triggers when setting a value of an undefined property in a class.  You're modifying a value, not setting one.

Comment: I think it cant be resolve as i was thinking as Rocket said, thanks every body for your help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an array, you can use a class that implements the ArrayAccess interface. This way you have full control over what occurs when you append to the array.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

The drawback is that not all array functions will work on the object (ie sorting etc), but you can push like so:

```
$object[] = 'new value';
```

The alternative is to simply make a wrapper function for adding to the array.

```
public function addToArray($key, $value) {
   if ($key === null) {
      $this->test[] = 'My extra value ' . $value;
   } else {
      $this->test[$key] = 'My extra value ' . $value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand what you're asking, but are you trying to do this:

```
$this->test['key'] = "some val";
```

That will allow you to setup your own output nicely. Because array_push() will throw on another nested level.

**Update: Maybe something along these lines?**

```
function push($prefix)
{
    $refl = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $prop = $refl->getProperties();
    foreach($prop as $p) {
        $this->{$p} = $prefix . $this->{$p};
    }
}
```

Comment: He's trying to add a prefix to all elements added to a class property (using `__set`).

Comment: As Rocket said, but the prefix its an example, in fact is gonna be other thing but for the help propouses is the same, The problem is that there is a program already made, that uses a lot the array push method, and i want to append some thing else, but __get and __set doesnt work for array push, event when a variable of the class its been affected

Comment: Can be using some thing else than __set or __get, but make the prefix thing

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for, I suggest you create yourself a function that prefixes any value independent to it's use:

```
function prefix($value) {
    return 'My extra value '.$value;
}
```

You can then make use of that function inside the `index()` function:

```
function index()
{
    $test = array("some val", "some other val");
    foreach($test as $value)
    {
        $this->test[] = $this->prefix($value);
    }
    print_r($this->test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual:

```
__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.
__get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.
```

This is only called on reading/writing inaccessible properties. Your property however is public, which means it is accessible. Changing the access modifier to protected solves the issue.

Try this:

```
    class ClassName {

        private $test = array();

        public function __set($attr, $value) {
          $this->test[$attr] = $value;

        }    

        public function __get($attr) {
        return $this->test[$attr];
        }    

        public function index(){

          array_push($this->test, "some val");
          array_push($this->test, "some other val");

          return $this->test;

        }
    }

    $o = new ClassName();
    $o->setData = 'My extra value';
    print_r($o->index());
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual says the following about magic methods:

> __set() is run when writing data to **inaccessible** properties. (Emphasis mine)

Because the `test` property is inside the method and the function that is accessing it is inside the method, the function will see the variable directly and will *not* use the magic setter.

Additionally, even if you try to use array_push on the magic setter **outside** the class itself, that still will not work.  You will get the error `array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`.

If you want to support array_push, you should write your own `push($item)` method:

```
function push($item) {
    $this->test[] = 'My extra value' . $item
}
```

or:

```
function push() {
    $items = func_get_args();

    // Using array_map is one of the many ways to do this.
    // You could also do it with a simpler `foreach` but I like this way.
    $prepend = function($item) {
        return 'My extra value' . $item;
    };
    $items = array_map($prepend, $items);
    array_push($this->test, $items);
}
```

if you want to support pushing multiple items at once.