# how to use array_push with multidimensional array with a class instanciation and how to deal with the id of the array

Tags: php, class, multidimensional-array, array-push

hi i'am using a mvc structure for my web site,
i have a class that contains a multidimensional array with a class instanciation in it like this:

```
protected $db;

/* Construit une instance avec 4 poèmes. */
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = array(
        "01" => new Poem("Ma bohème", "rimbaud.jpg", "Arthur Rimbaud", "boheme"),
        "02" => new Poem("J'ai tant rêvé de toi", "desnos.jpg", "Robert Desnos", "reve"),
        "03" => new Poem("Chanson d'automne", "verlaine.jpg", "Paul Verlaine", "sanglots"),
        "04" => new Poem("Liberté", "eluard.jpg", "Paul Éluard", "liberte"),
    );
}
```

my question is how to use array_push to add values in it.(these values are from a form)
and how to deal with the id of the array

Comment: 1. Where and how do you want to use `array_push()` ? 2. You know that you can't use `array_push()` with associative keys.

Comment: i want to add new values to my db array (i want to use it like a database)

Comment: As you show us the array now you won't be able to push new values with an associative key. Also you can't use an array like a db.

Comment: It's not multidimensional. One way: `$this->db['05'] = ...` or simply `$this->db[] = ...`. Read more in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push item to associative array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206020/push-item-to-associative-array-in-php)

Comment: ok,  then how i can solve this problem and add new values to this array??

Comment: see this post about this exact issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094007/php-magic-method-to-catch-array-push

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might help,

1. create an object $class = new Poem("Your values");
2. array_push($this->db, $class);

OR 
array_push($this->db, new Poem("Your values"));

Comment: *Err.* You can't push new values with associative keys as in OP's array shown.

Comment: string key "01" is wrong for this question you asked. Replace it with int 0.  0 => new poem(),1 => new poem()....When you use array_push , it will automatically add key to it. You don’t have to create it